# Disable automatic submenu show on hover in ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, contextmenustrip

If I have a context menu with sub menu items,  is it possible to stop the sub menu from popping out/displaying when I merely hover over the main menu item?  And if so,  how?

[image: Submenu item example screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `ToolStripDropDownItem` has a property called `DropDown` (of type `ToolStripDropDown`) referring to the drop down which will be shown when the mouse hovers on the item. The `ToolStripDropDown` has an event called `Opening` which allows you to cancel the dropping-down easily. Use the following code, all can be set up in your form constructor:

```
//Suppose the item you want to suppress automatically showing 
//the drop down is item1
bool clicked = false;
item1.DropDown.Opening += (s,e) => {
  e.Cancel = !clicked;
  clicked = false;
};
item1.Click += (s,e) => {
  clicked = true;
  item1.ShowDropDown();
};
//The code above disables the automatic dropping-down 
//and shows the drop down by clicking on the item1.
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thankyou!

I notice some syntax I've never seen before. I'm new to c#.  I guess that's a way to override methods c#?  I will google that to learn more.

Comment: @MrVimes the syntax I used is called `lambda expression`, it's just a convenient way for building `delegate` easily, the code is just used to register the `Opening` and `Click` event handlers. It's not `override`, to override you have to create some class inherits from the base class and override the base methods in there.